# jqrid - adding cellattr to json colmodel

Tags: javascript, json, jqgrid

I have been trying to add a `cellattr` function to my `colmodel` json response but cannot seem to get it to fire. I have tried adding classes and styles but thought I would try and log 
something out to see if I could get it to work.

Here is a snippet from my returned json:

```
{
"name":"15/09/2012",
"index":"Sep 2012",
"align":"center",
"width":30,
"frozen":false,
"sortable":false,
"cellattr":"function (rowId, tv, rawObject, cm, rdata) { console.log('test'); 
}
```

Was wondering if anyone had any experience with this and could point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at colModel at [Wiki fro JQgrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acolmodel_options) The cellattr is or type function and not string so you need to have something like this

```
{
"name":"15/09/2012",
"index":"Sep 2012",
"align":"center",
"width":30,
"frozen":false,
"sortable":false,
"cellattr":"myfunction" 
}

function myfunction(rowId,val,rawObject,cm,rdata)
{
      return "some string";
}
```

The way you were defining the function is only defining a string and not an actual js function.

if you are stuck with inline definitions you can use function(){} format to create new anonymous function.